# Match every row data with a list of columns information

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a list of values in column `A` and it's occurrences for a an event in rows 3 & 4 (As in figure I). For every value in `A`, I need to search its existence in rows 3 & 4. If it present then I need to copy paste the value in its intersection with the column (As in figure II). Is is possible to achieve this by using excel-formula?

[image: Input]

[image: Output]

Comment: You can use `MATCH()` for this. This question is a better match for SuperUser though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste the following formula into C7:

```
=IF(OR($A7=C$3,$A7=C$4),$A7,"")
```

Then drag the formula (using the little green box in the corner of the cell) to F9 (or whatever is the correct cell to capture all the rows and columns).

The formula checks if the value in column A is the same as the value in row 3 *or* row 4. If true, it puts the value from column A. If false, it puts blank.

If you actually have more than 2 rows to check against, `OR` could become impractical. In that case, you would want to use `MATCH`, like so:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A7,C$3:C$4,0)),"",$A7)
```

In this case, the formula works by checking if the value in column A matches any of the values in rows 3 *to* 4. If the match fails (is an error), it puts blank. If the match succeeds (no error), it puts the value from column A.